# Getting unknown named module error in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, babeljs

Im trying to use what3words. But when the app first calls the API, crashes with `Unknown named module '/utils'`. I have downgraded to 3.1.0 since the latest also gave similar error but for `./constants`. I dont think the error is related to w3w but maybe my babel config.

```
Binaries:
    Node: 14.16.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - /opt/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.11 - /usr/local/bin/npm
npmPackages:
    react: ~16.9.0 => 16.9.0
    react-native: ~0.61.4 => 0.61.5
    @babel/cli: ^7.10.4 => 7.10.4
    @babel/core: ^7.10.4 => 7.10.4
    @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties: ^7.3.0 => 7.10.1
    @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators: ^7.8.3 => 7.10.3
    @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread: ^7.4.5 => 7.10.3
    @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining: 7.9.0 => 7.9.0
    @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types: ^7.10.4 => 7.10.4
    @babel/plugin-transform-regenerator: ^7.4.5 => 7.10.3
    @babel/polyfill: ^7.4.4 => 7.10.1
    @babel/preset-env: ^7.4.5 => 7.10.3
    @babel/preset-flow: ^7.10.4 => 7.10.4
    @babel/preset-react: ^7.0.0 => 7.10.1
    @babel/preset-typescript: ^7.3.3 => 7.10.1
    @babel/runtime: ^7.4.5 => 7.10.3
    babel-jest: ^26.1.0 => 26.1.0
    babel-preset-react-native: ^4.0.1 => 4.0.1
    jest: ^26.1.0 => 26.1.0
    metro-react-native-babel-preset: ^0.59.0 => 0.59.0
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset', '@babel/preset-flow'],
  env: {
    production: {
      plugins: ['react-native-paper/babel'],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
      ['@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types'],
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }]
  ]
};
```

metro.config.js

```
// /* eslint-disable import/no-commonjs */

const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');
const escape = require('escape-string-regexp');

const modules = [
  '@babel/runtime',
  '@expo/vector-icons',
];

module.exports = {
  projectRoot: __dirname,

  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

Please suggest. Thanks.